# Add days to date

Tags: javascript, date

I found a piece of code which add days to the given date. However it only works when date is in `YY-MM-DD` format but it is not working if it is in `DD-MM-YY` format.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Je4Up/) for `YY-MM-DD` format **(Working)**

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4RZAa/) for `DD-MM-YY` format **(Not Working)**

I further checked that if i do an alert for `someDate.getDate()` it says `NaN` Not A Number

```
someDate = new Date('27-08-2013');
alert(someDate.getDate()); //NaN
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: That is just because the `Date` method only accepts it as 'MM-DD-YYYY'

Comment: Yes, the Date constructor requires a certain format (the one Date.parse uses: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse). You should convert other dates to this format first. Also see http://xkcd.com/1179/.

Comment: If a library is ok for you then you could look at [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/).

Comment: You could also do `new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)`

Comment: So i probably have to stick with `YY-MM-DD` format and add days to it and than use the `split` method to rearrange the date in desired format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input is DD-MM-YY you can try to  `split` the string. Check my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/4RZAa/1/

I `split` the string and afterwards enter the desired format in the date function.

Answer (score 1):

I always create 7 functions, to work with date in JS: addSeconds, addMinutes, addHours, addDays, addWeeks, addMonths, addYears.
They all work in any format.

You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/tiagoajacobi/YHA8x/

How to use:

```
var now = new Date();
console.log(now.addWeeks(3));
```

This are the functions:

```
        Date.prototype.addSeconds = function(seconds) {
            this.setSeconds(this.getSeconds() + seconds);
            return this;
        };

        Date.prototype.addMinutes = function(minutes) {
            this.setMinutes(this.getMinutes() + minutes);
            return this;
        };

        Date.prototype.addHours = function(hours) {
            this.setHours(this.getHours() + hours);
            return this;
        };

        Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
            this.setDate(this.getDate() + days);
            return this;
        };

        Date.prototype.addWeeks = function(weeks) {
            this.addDays(weeks*7);
            return this;
        };

        Date.prototype.addMonths = function (months) {
            var dt = this.getDate();

            this.setMonth(this.getMonth() + months);
            var currDt = this.getDate();

            if (dt !== currDt) {  
                this.addDays(-currDt);
            }

            return this;
        };

        Date.prototype.addYears = function(years) {
            var dt = this.getDate();

            this.setFullYear(this.getFullYear() + years);

            var currDt = this.getDate();

            if (dt !== currDt) {  
                this.addDays(-currDt);
            }

            return this;
        };
```